# Entity Framework, identity column with another entity in one SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'll simplify my problem. I have 1 class with these properties:
Id
IdFollower
Some other columns...

Then I have existing entity with ID = 1. I want to create another one and set IdFollower to existing one with Id from new one.

Is it possible to make it with only one `SaveChanges`. I have tried but with no luck. For example:

```
var existing = context.class.Find(1);
var nextInLine = new class(){....}
context.class.Add(nextInLine);
existing.IdFollower = nextInLine.Id
context.SaveChanges();
```

I expected that EF knows what nextInLine is new record (its state is `Added`) and wont write "0" in `IdFollower` on existing Entity but rather first save nextInLine, get its Id and writes that Id in existing Entity and then save existing Entity.

For now I'm using it so I have one extra `SaveChanges()` just after `context.class.Add(nextInLine)`. So at the end it looks like:

```
var nextInLine = new class(){....}
context.class.Add(nextInLine);
context.SaveChanges();
existing.IdFollower = nextInLine.Id
context.SaveChanges();
```

I have used so far another ORM but I want to swith to EF. This "problem" was not present n that ORM.

Is it possible to have it with 1 `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but instead of set the FK property set the relationship through the navigation property in the `existing` entity:

```
var existing = context.class.Find(1);
var nextInLine = new Follower(){....};
context.class.Add(nextInLine);
existing.Follower = nextInLine;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Set the FK property when you need to relate an entity with another existing entity that is already persisted in your DB.
If you need more info check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx).

Comment: I tried that (I did not have self reference link). Thanx. Its make sense totaly!